# Check database every 12 hours in ios app

Tags: ios, push-notification

In my app, I want to check my database every 12 hours for an entry and if found, set a notification.In android,it is accomplished by using a service.But in ios services are not allowed.I tried to implement NSTimer,but it will be reset when the app goes to background.I want my service to be run when the app is on background. On research the only possible way I found is to use push notification.But if the network is  disconnected,push notification will not work and notification will not be set that day.Is there any other possible way to implement my requirement please?

Answer (score 1):

Long-running background processes are only allowed for VOIP applications that need to maintain an open connection to a server.

Push notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered, however, if your server sends your iOS device a push notification, the notification will be queued at the APNS server residing at Apple. When the target device is reconnected to APNS, the notification will be delivered.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.That will be enough.I'll try this and let you know

Comment: Push notifications have many disadvantages like they can be expensive and they may not be delivered on time. Is there any other method to fulfill my need than push notification?

Comment: Furthermore, if the app is closed, your notification could arrive to the iPhone but it will not be handled by your app, you will only show your alert message/sound to the user and only if he taps the notification and open your app you could execute your code. You cannot trust in push notifications for this kind of task

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can check the database is when your app is running. You can't do it when your app is on background.

Only VOIP, Music and Location based applications can run on background for long durations.

You can use [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to alert the user to open your app.